# How to do an operation over each row from a select?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, triggers

I'm trying to do an operation with the values from each row of a select in a trigger, but i don't know how to start designing this algorithm.

```
create trigger trigger_updCompleta
after update on tableA
for each row
begin

    update tableB
    set tableB.est='reserved'
    where   tableB.id_e= attr1_from_a_row_of_select and
            tableB.num_a= attr2_from_a_row_of_select and
            tableB.num_g= attr3_from_a_row_of_select;
end//
```

this is the select from which i want to compare the values

```
select c.id_e, c.num_g, c.num_a, c.t from tableC as c
    where c.id_r=tableA;
```

My tables are this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableA(
    id_r INT NOT NULL,
    id_c INT NOT NULL REFERENCES cliente (id_cliente),
    completed BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_r)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableB(
    id_e INT NOT NULL REFERENCES grada (id_e),
    num_g INT NOT NULL REFERENCES grada (num_g),
    num_a INT NOT NULL,
    est ENUM('reserved', 'libre', 'pre-reservado', 'deteriorado') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'libre',
    PRIMARY KEY (id_e , num_g , num_a)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableC(
    id_r INT NOT NULL REFERENCES reserva (id_reserva),
    id_e INT NOT NULL REFERENCES localidad (id_evento),
    num_g INT NOT NULL REFERENCES localidad (num_grada),
    num_a INT NOT NULL REFERENCES localidad (num_asiento),
    t ENUM('bebe', 'infantil', 'adulto', 'parado', 'jubilado') NOT NULL     REFERENCES precio (t),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_r , id_e , num_g , num_a)
);
```

I'm trying that when i update a row on tableA, automatically change the value of tableB.est to reserved, for each rows in which tableB.id_e, tableB.num_a and tableB.num_g be the same that the values c.id_e, c.num_g, c.num_a from the select

Comment: How does your table look, and what is the result you are looking for?

Comment: by `tableB.id_e = attr1_from_a_row_of_select` do you mean to do `tableB.id_e = NEW.attr1`

Comment: no, I mean one of the atribues that the select return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I solve it for my self

```
begin

    if new.completed=true then
    update tableB,(select e.id_e as ev ,e.num_g as grad ,e.num_a as asient,e.t as tip from tableC as e, tableA as r 
                            where e.id_r=r.id_r) sel
    set tableB.e= 'reserved' 
    where tableB.id_e= ev and
          tableB.num_a= asient and
          tableB.num_g= grad;
    ELSE
    update tableB,(select e.id_e as ev ,e.num_g as grad ,e.num_a as asient,e.t as tip from tableC as e, tableA as r 
                            where e.id_r=r.id_r) sel
    set tableB.e= 'pre-reserved' 
    where tableB.id_e= ev and
          tableB.num_a= asient and
          tableB.num_g= grad;
    end if;

end//
```

I wish that this could help anyone